# Send email using Gmail and TLS on WebLogic

Tags: java, email, ssl

Here is the code I'm using to send an email:

```
    Properties smtpProps = new Properties();
    smtpProps.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(SMTP_PROPERTIES_FILE));

    // Load from email properties
    Properties emailProps = new Properties();
    emailProps.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(EMAIL_PROPERTIES_FILE));

    // We could setup a mail session from the Weblogic server
    Session session = Session.getInstance(smtpProps, null);

    // Create a new message
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Set the from and to
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailProps.getProperty(EMAIL_PROPERTY_NAME)));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

    // Message content
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setText(message, MESSAGE_ENCODING);

    // Send the email
    String host     = smtpProps.getProperty(HOST_PROPERTY_NAME);
    String username = emailProps.getProperty(EMAIL_PROPERTY_NAME);
    String password = emailProps.getProperty(PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME);

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, 587, username, password);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

And the properties file I'm using:

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.protocol.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
```

When I run it on WebLogic (as a webservice) I get the following error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;   nested exception is:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I think so, you need to add gmail's cert to your webSphere.

Comment: But by adding this: mail.protocol.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com shouldn't it be required?

Comment: You need this too, but you need download gmail's certs and add in websphere console, I don't have websphere in my PC now to show step by step to you. sorry :(

Comment: Maybe it work for you http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_5.0.0/admin/install/t_exchange_keys_network.dita